# What is the condition that k complex polynomials in k variables have a finite number of common zeros?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

**What is the condition that *k* complex polynomials in *k* variables have a finite number of common zeros?**

Background: The following is a version of Bezout's theorem:

> Let there be 2 complex polynomials in 2 variables. If they are coprime, then the number of common zeros is finite and bounded by the product of their degrees.

I am interested in generalizing this to *k* complex polynomials in *k* variables. I already found a proof that if the number of common zeros is finite then it has the bound I want, for example, in [this blog post by Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/bezouts-inequality/) (Theorem 4). However, the condition for finiteness is not specified.

I thought the generalization is "pairwise coprime", but this is wrong. Let $k=3$ and consider the counterexample $x,y,x+y$ (as polynomials in $x,y,z$). As a less trivial counterexample, consider $x-z, y-z, x^2+y^2-2z^2$, for which any $x=y=z$ works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition is that the polynomials generate an ideal of [height](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IdealHeight.html) $k$.

This is much harder to check for $k>2$ than $k=2$, because height $1$ primes are principal in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$, so we just need to check that our polynomials have no common factors.

Comment: Thank you! One follow up question: I'd like to argue that any $k$ polynomials in $k$ variables will have a finite number of common zeros after a small perturbation. How do I argue this?

Comment: @YoniRozenshein If you already have $f_1,\ldots, f_j$, then the condition on $f_{j+1}$ is that the hypersurface $V(f_{j+1})$ must not contain an irreducible component of the variety $V(f_1,\ldots, f_j)$.  Since there are only finitely many components, a general polynomial near $f_j$ will have this property.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not yet versed enough in algebraic geometry to understand these "general" arguments. Can the property of "infinitely many common zeroes" be written as an algebraic condition on the coefficients of the polynomials? If so, I can argue that it is a Zariski-closed subset of the coefficient choice space, and one example is enough to show that it is negligible. This is the only "general argument" I understand so far...

Comment: @YoniRozenshein Specifying a certain zero is an algebraic constraint on the coefficients.  So specifying many zeros gives us a Zariski closed set in the coefficient space also.

Comment: For example, if all the polynomials were linear (suppose $k=3$ and $f_j(x,y,z) = a_{1j} x + a_{2j} y + a_{3j} z$ for $j=1,2,3$), then the algebraic condition for infinitely many zeroes is $\det (a_{ij}) = 0$. Is there such a condition for higher orders? The condition shouldn't be "specified zeroes" but just "infinitely many zeroes".

Comment: @YoniRozenshein This is yet a third way to look at it.  We want the the zero locus not to contain any curve.  Given some irreducible curve $C\subset \mathbb{C}^n$, the condition that each of our polynomials belongs to $I(C)$ is a Zariski-closed condition.  Intersecting all of these conditions tells us exactly when the zero locus is more-than-zero-dimensional, which is equivalent to being infinite.

Comment: That sounds like a good direction. But how do I generalize $C$? I mean, it sounds like the intersection of the conditions says that the polynomials contain some specific predetermined curve $C$ - and not that they contain *any* curve, as in the linear example (determinant is zero -> locus contains a line, but it's unknown which one).

Comment: @YoniRozenshein Intersect the conditions for all curves.

Comment: But there are (uncountably) infinite curves... the union is not going to be Zariski-closed.

Comment: @YoniRozenshein Sorry, you're right, this approach was too optimistic.  I think I would argue inductively, as before.  This condition seems most naturally stated as: each successive $f_{j+1}$ decreases the dimension by $1$.  So we check this on each irreducible component and verify that this happens on a dense subset of whatever space we're using to model polynomials.